# Cohomology in vector bundles and extensions

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

I am studying a certain problem arising in holomorphic vector bundles over a complex manifold $X$.

My goal is to understand how to catalogue the possible extensions of two given (holomorphic) vector bundles $E_1,E_2$ over $X$, i.e. all possible $E$ fitting a exact sequence of the form
$$ 0 \rightarrow E_1 \rightarrow E \rightarrow E_2
\rightarrow 0$$
I have been directed towards something denoted as $H^1(X,E_1\otimes E_2^*)$, which I suppose is certain cohomology group, as a parametrization for these extensions $E$.

I would like to learn precisely how to construct such an extension from this group explicitly.

As reference, my background encompasses de Rham cohomology and the notion of sheaves, besides the bijection between locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules and holomorphic vector bundles, and a little bit of Dolbeault cohomology, but I lack many of the basics of algebraic geometry.

Any outline of where to even start reading would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably more usual to think of it as the [Ext group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#Ext_and_extensions) $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{X}(E_2,E_1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not necessairly the ideal answer, but i would say the following.

The vector bundle $E_2^* \otimes E_1$ has the local endomorphisms from $E_2$ to $E_1$ as local sections.

Over an open $U$ where the two vector bundles are trivial, the exact sequence splits so there is a $s_U : E_2|_U \longrightarrow E|_U$ such that $p|_U \circ s_U = Id$ where $p$ stands for the second arrow.

Over an intersection, when you compose $p$ with the difference $s_{U_1}-s_{U_2}$ it must therefore be zero : so this difference has values in $E_1 = ker(p)$.

So $(s_{U_1}-s_{U_2})_{U_1,U_2}$ is a cocycle with values in $E_2^* \otimes E_1$.

Conversely, you can glue together the directs sums $E_1|_U \oplus E_2|_U$ using the transitions $\psi_{1,2},\varphi_{1,2}$ of $E_1$ and $E_2$ and a cocycle as previously. In an explicit way, you have the sum of  two trivial bundles over $U_1$ and $U_2$ and the transition is a matrice $$\begin{pmatrix} \psi_{1,2} &s_{1,2}\\ 0 & \varphi_{1,2} \end{pmatrix}$$ where $s_{1,2}$ is the matrice of the endomorphism corredponding to the cocycle over $U_1 \cap U_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Should I understand that this $H^1(X,E_1 \otimes E_2^*)$ is simply related to sections of the bundle $E_1\otimes E_2^*$? I thought this was usually denoted by $H^0$.

Secondly, could you comment why when localize the exact sequence splits?

Comment: Its may be not very rigourous but $H^1$ stands for collections $(s_{\alpha,\beta})_{\alpha,\beta \in A}$ where $s_{\alpha,\beta}$ is a section over $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$ for a "fine" covering $(U_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$.

Comment: In fact they are classes of such collections modulo those which are of the form $(s_\alpha - s_\beta)_{\alpha,\beta}$

Comment: When you localize over an open where all bundles are tivial, then they are spanned by global sections. So you can do as in linear algebra : you choose a basis for the kernel $E_1$, you complete into a basis of $E$. The splitting is given by projecting on the submodule spanned by the complementary sections.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying, I now see how locally there is a splitting. However I am still on the fence about these cocycles. Do they build up to be global sections of $Hom(E_2,E_1)\simeq E_1\otimes E_2^*$?

Comment: Maybe it’s worth pointing out that this uses the Cech cohomology group of the bundle (which is isomorphic to whatever we’ve defined these cohomology by). That’s probably the way to go if you want to explicitly construct an extension. Another way of defining the cohomology class of an extension is to put a Hermitian metric on the middle bundle and use the Dolbeault class of the adjoint of the second fundamental form. I don’t see off-hand how to construct an extension given just such a class though.

Comment: @topolosaurus : A cocycle is roughly a collection $(s_{\alpha,\beta})_{\alpha \neq \beta}$ of sections over intersections of two distinct opens of a fine covering. In general, there is no reason to find a collection $(s_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ such that $s_{\alpha,\beta}= s_\alpha|_{U_\alpha \cap U_\beta}- s_\beta|_{U_\alpha \cap U_\beta}$. When it is the case, we say that it is a coboundary : the quotient is the Chech cohomology as pointed out by Gunnar Magnùsson.